# react lazy with async dynamic imports causes wrong orders in deployment

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-lazy-load, react-async

I'm using react, typescript. This is part of my code using react lazy.

```
import {lazy} from 'react';

const LAZY_PANELS = {};
const PANELS = {
  'home': () => import('./home'),
  'settings': () => import('./settings'),
  'profile': () => import('./profile'),
}
for (const route of Object.keys(PANELS)) {
  LAZY_PANELS[PANELS[route]] = lazy(PANELS[route]);
}
```

I'm using PANELS object to render my components and it's working fine. after adding `@typescript-eslint/promise-function-async` to my eslint rules i needed to change my code like this:

```
import {lazy} from 'react';

const LAZY_PANELS = {};
const PANELS = {
  'home': async () => import('./home'),
  'settings': async () => import('./settings'),
  'profile': async () => import('./profile'),
}
for (const route of Object.keys(PANELS)) {
  LAZY_PANELS[PANELS[route]] = lazy(PANELS[route]);
}
```

I did it and everything was OK but after creating a new build in deployed version lazy components are not in correct order. `PANELS.home` is equal to profile component and `PANELS.profile` is equal to home component.

I know that if I remove asyncs and disable that rule here or even use `checkArrowFunctions` option to ignore arrow functions it's gonna be OK but i rather to know the reason why it's happening and maybe solve it in a better way.

Comment: Welcome to SO! "_lazy components are not in correct order_": how do you notice that? Are you referring to loading order? How do you use `LAZY_PANELS`?

Comment: I mean they are stored in the `LAZY_PANELS` by wrong order.
`LAZY_PANELS[PANELS[home]]` is equal to profile component and `LAZY_PANELS[PANELS[profile]]` is equal to home component.

Comment: It seems to be related to resolving time of promises but i don't know why it's not happening in develop and how to fix it.

Comment: Can you store them just as `LAZY_PANELS[route]`?

Comment: Good point, I guess changing it will solve the problem.
I know that it was a bad implementation that was  in project's base structure from years ago but do you know why its not working properly in deploy mode?

It's working with `() => import('./path')` and because its returning a promise by the definition adding async to it shouldn't change anything. it's kinda weird.